# Default and value constructed objects have different types

Tags: default-constructor, value-constructor

Consider the following code with one variable default constructed and the other one value constructed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A
{
    A() : m_() {}
    A(int m) : m_(m) {}

    int m_;
};

int main()
{
    A a, b(), c(5);

    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(c).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With GCC 4.8 the output is

> A
>
> A ()
>
> A

So `a,c` and `b` have different types although they refer to the same struct/class. How can this be?

(Of course, this is a minimal example derived from an issue of a complex code. There, I get something like `A` vs. `A(int)` but I can't reproduce this yet.)

Comment: I suppose that the definition of `b` is interpreted as a function definition. But why, what are the rules for it?

Comment: The solution to my original problem was a typo, how embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `A b()` means that `b` is a function of signature `A ()`, notwithstanding the fact it is mixed with declarations of variables `a` and `c` of type `A`. The following modifications to the example code make it clearer:

```
struct X {};

struct A
{
    A() : m_() {}
    A(X m) : m_(m) {}

    X m_;
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    A a, b(x), c(X);

    ...
}
```

The output is

> A
>
> A
>
> A (X)

So `a` and `b` are default and value constructed, resp., but `c` is a function declaration and thus of different type.